# GLSL fragment shader struct out

Tags: opengl, compilation, glsl, shader

i have a problem with my GLSL shader.
When i want to compile the fragment shader part, i get the following error:

```
0:24: error(#181) Cannot be used with a structure: out
error(#273) 1 compilation errors. No code generated
```

So the problem lies around my out variable, i assume.
Here is my fragment shader:

```
#version 410

uniform mat4 gWVP;
uniform mat4 gWorld;

uniform sampler2D gColorMap;                

in VSOutput
{
    vec3 WorldSpacePos;
    vec2 TexCoord;
    vec3 Normal;  
} FSin;


struct FSOutput
{                   
    vec3 WorldSpacePos;    
    vec3 Diffuse;     
    vec3 Normal;      
    vec3 TexCoord;
};

out FSOutput FSOut;

void main()
{                                           
    FSOut.WorldSpacePos = FSin.WorldSpacePos;                   
    FSOut.Diffuse      = texture(gColorMap, FSin.TexCoord).xyz; 
    FSOut.Normal       = normalize(FSin.Normal);                    
    FSOut.TexCoord     = vec3(FSin.TexCoord, 0.0);              
}
```

As i know it should be possible to output structs in OpenGL 4.0+, shouldn't it? So I dont get the error, is it a driver problem or something like that?
I'm running on a Radeon HD 6950 with 13.4 drivers.

Comment: Some stages allow you to output structures, fragment shaders are not one of those stages. The outputs from a fragment shader are pretty strict - the closest you could get to what you want is to use an array of vec3; this is similar to the way the old `gl_FragData [n]` construct worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As i know it should be possible to output structs in OpenGL 4.0+, shouldn't it?

No, it shouldn't.

The GLSL specification is quite clear on this: vertex shader inputs and fragment shader outputs *cannot* be structs. From the GLSL 4.4 specification, section 4.3.6:

> Fragment outputs can only be float, single-precision floating-point vectors, signed or unsigned integers or integer vectors, or arrays of any these. It is a compile-time error to declare any double-precision type, matrix, or structure as an output.

They also can't be aggregated into [interface blocks](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Interface_Block), in case you're wondering. They must be loose variables.

Comment: ah ok, well then I just misunderstood something. Well actually i got most of this shader from a tutorial. Why would he explain something wrong?

Comment: @C0dR: Can you link the tutorial? Perhaps it's a misinterpretation, or more likely it was a quick hackjob of a translation from an HLSL shader to GLSL.

Comment: The original tutorial used glfx, but I printed out the "translated" shaders out of glfx:
http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial35/tutorial35.html

Comment: @C0dR: First, that's not the translated shader, as evidenced by the fact that it uses a struct. Either that, or GLfx is broken. Second, why would you use an OpenGL tutorial that refuses to actually *use OpenGL*? What good is learning "GLfx script" rather than the actual GLSL?

Comment: It was the only good(?) tutorial i found with deferred rendering content. So might glfx be broken? i tried every public version